# Reading a set of integers as a string in C++

Tags: c++, parsing

I have the following text file   numbers.txt

```
4 
5
825
6725
6244865
```

Basically, I wanna take the integer in the first line (4 in this case), as integer and 
take the remaining integers as string, and I wrote the following code:

```
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("numbers.txt");
int a;
inFile>>a;
string b[a];
for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
inFile>>b[i];
}
```

but it doesn't work. Is there something I did wrong in this code?
I also used getline, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: `string b[a]` Nope...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string b[a];
```

is not going to fly, you cannot allocate arrays of non-const size like that. Either do

```
string* b = new string[a];
```

and later

```
delete[] b;
```

Or make something like a vector of strings:

```
vector <string> b(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int a;
inFile>>a;
string b[a];
```

This should not even compile. You cannot declare an array with a size that will be determined at runtime.

Do the following:

```
int a = -1;
inFile>>a;
if (a < 1) {
   // HANDLE INVALID DATA HERE!
}

vector<string> b(a);
for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
    inFile>>b[i];
}
```